# Create a derivation in Nix to only copy some files

Tags: build, nix

I have some files in a folder that I want to create a derivation out of to pass them as inputs to `dockerTools.buildImage` later.

I'm not sure how to do this. This doesn't work:

```hs
database = pkgs.stdenv.mkDerivation {
  name = "database";
  src = "./";
  phases = [ "installPhase" ];
  installPhase = ''
      pwd
      ls -al
      echo $src
      cp $src/.env $out
      cp $src/20221002.sqlite $out
  '';
};
```

Because `cp` can't find the files.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out this is what's necessary for this to work:

```hs
database = pkgs.stdenv.mkDerivation {
  name = "database";
  src = ./.;
  phases = [ "unpackPhase" "installPhase" ];
  installPhase = ''
    mkdir -p $out
    cp $src/.env $out
    cp $src/20221002.sqlite $out
  '';
};
```

The `src` attribute needs to point to the current directory and then everything in there will be copied over.

The copying only happens when `unpackPhase` is part of the phases.

Then in the `installPhase` we need to drop into shell to do the actual work. `$out` means the output path of the derivation and `$src` is set to the folder of the `src`. In many cases $out is just a file but in this case since we want it to contain two files, we have to `mkdir` it first and then we can `cp` both files into it.

Comment: Nice work, that's basically it yes. Some comments: 1) `$out` is not in many cases a file--in fact, it being a directory is vastly more common. 2) It is rarely a good idea customize the `phases`. Instead, I advise using `dontUnpack = true`, removing the phases, and leaving everything else as-is. C.f. https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/28910 3) if you don't use the compiler (like here) you can use `pkgs.stdenvNoCC.mkDerivation`, it's lighter for systems that don't need the whole build chain.

Comment: @hraban Can you give an example for what you advised (for beginers like me)?

Comment: @snaeil Sorry I'm afraid I don't understand the question. Advise what for what do you mean?

Comment: I found this article useful to solve the same problem in a different way: https://nix.dev/tutorials/working-with-local-files.html#union-explicitly-include-files